# Powershell Terminal encoding in VSCode

Tags: powershell, encoding, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode editor for Powershell scripts. And I have the problem with paths, which contains cyrillic characters. For example code:

```
$users = 'C:\Users\Тестовый пользователь\Documents\userlist.csv'
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $u = Get-Content -LiteralPath $users
    Write-Host "Пользователь:" $u
}
```

return the error:

> Cannot find path 'C:\Users\РќРёР°СЂРјРµРґРє\Documents\userlist.csv"'
>   because it does not exist.

Comment: first of all, dont use vscode terminal, it sucks. second, pick russian as a non unicode system locale: https://java.com/en/download/help/locale.xml

Comment: Problem solved! I just resave file as utf8bom.

Comment: Wuy vscode terminal is sucks? Wich alternative?

Comment: I guess you saved it as UTF-8 without BOM before? PowerShell tries to read it as ASCII. The BOM will tell it to use UTF-8 instead. Or you could change PowerShell's default encoding.

Comment: powershell terminal

Comment: @4c74356b41 you can set PowerShell as your VSCode terminal ;)

Comment: link, por favor @gvee?

Comment: @4c74356b41 how  set PowerShell as VSCode terminal?

Comment: i have no idea, asking @gvee

Comment: The setting is [`terminal.integrated.shell.windows`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration). On the UI this is found under `File > Settings > Features > Terminal`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the encoding with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), Powershell will read the file with its default encoding (mostly ASCII): [Understanding default encoding and Change the same in PowerShell](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/03/03/understanding-default-encoding-and-change-the-same-in-powershell/)

VS Code doesn't set a `bom` in its default configuration. To avoid this problem in further PowerShell scripts, add [these options in your VS Code settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-6#configuring-vscode):

```
{
    "[powershell]": {
        "files.encoding": "utf8bom",
        "files.autoGuessEncoding": true
     },
}
```

Alternatively you could also change your powershell default encoding ofc.